# Intersection of two plane curves in the residue field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, algebraic-curves, plane-curves, intersection-theory

I want to propose this problem.

Suppose that $C:F(X,Y,Z)=0,\;C':G(X,Y,Z)=0$ are two plane curves defined over a number field $K$. Suppose that they have no common component and that all the intersection points are defined over $K$. Let $\mathfrak{p}$ a prime of the ring of integers $\mathcal{O}_K$. Let $\kappa(\mathfrak{p})$ the residue field. Assume that $F,G\in \mathcal{O}_\mathfrak{p}[X,Y,Z]$ have coprime coefficients,
denote by $\bar{F}$ and $\bar{G}$ the reduced polynomials in $\kappa(\mathfrak{p})[X,Y,Z]$.

Let $\bar{C}$ and $\bar{C'}$ the curves in $\mathbb{P}^n(\overline\kappa(\mathfrak{p}))$ respectively defined by the equations $\bar{F}(X,Y,Z)=0$ and $\bar{G}(X,Y,Z)=0$. Suppose that
$\bar{C}$ and $\bar{C'}$ have no common component.

CLAIM: All the intersection points of $\bar{C}\cap\bar{C'}$ can be lifted to intersection points of $C\cap C'$.

My idea: The number of intersection points (counting multiplicities) is $\deg(\bar{C})\deg(\bar{C'})=\deg(C)\deg(C')$ by Bezout theorem.
So, if we are able to prove that the reduction map preserves the intersection numbers, we have finished. For "preserves the intersection numbers" i mean that if $P_1,..,P_t$ are all the points of $C\cap C'$ sent to $\bar{P}\in \bar{C}\cap\bar{C'}$ by the reduction map, then
$$I(\bar{P},\bar{C}\cap\bar{C'})=\sum_{i=1}^t I(P_i,C\cap C') %$$ 
This fact is somewhat intuitive, but i'm not able to formalize.

Thanks to every one who will help me.

Comment: The fact about intersection number is true if one of the curves is a line.
In fact assuming that we are intersecting $Z=0$ and $G(X,Y,Z)=0$, where $G(X,Y,Z)\in\mathcal{O}_\mathfrak{p}[X,Y,Z]$ and $G(X,Y,0)\nequiv 0\mod{\mathfrak{p}}$, then
$$G(X,Y,0)=c\cdot(a_1X+b_1Y)^{e_1)}\cdots(a_nX+b_nY)^{e_n}$$

Comment: So the points of intersection are $[b_i:-a_i]$ and clearly
$$I([b_i:-a_i],C\cap C')=e_i$$
If we suppose that $[b_1:-a_1],...,[b_r:-a_r]$ reduces to $[b_1:-a_1]\mod{\mathfrak{p}}$. Then it is clear that
$$I([\bar{b_1}:-\bar{a_1}],\bar{C}\cap\bar{C'})=e_1+...+e_r$$